# Create a list of dictionaries with only 3 items

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I have this variable that I get from a txt file, the file is not parsed, it is a big string.

```
- name: DEBUG
  debug:
    var: data
```

this is the full variable string:

```
 {
    "data": [
        "alexandria \tA\t10.10.3.202\t",
        "alexandria\tTXT\t\"this is a test\"\t",
        "alexandria\tMX\t10 relay.something.com.\t",
        "cname2\tCNAME\talexandria\t",
        "north A 200.200.200.200",
        "cname1 CNAME north",
        "rice CNAME redirect02.testttt.com.",
        "record01 a 10.10.10.10    ",
        "record02 a 10.10.10.11    "
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries from that:

```
- name: CONVERT STRING DATA INTO A DICTIONARY LIST
  set_fact:
    dict_list: "{{ dict_list|default([]) +
                  [{'data': item | split | first ,
                    'name': item | split }]  }}"
  loop: "{{ data }}"
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
{
    "data": "alexandria",
    "name": [
        "A",
        "10.10.3.202"
    ]
},
```

but I get instead:

```
{
    "data": "alexandria",
    "name": [
        "alexandria",
        "A",
        "10.10.3.202"
    ]
},
```

Also, another problem I have with that is this result:

```
{
    "data": "alexandria",
    "name": [
        "alexandria",
        "TXT",
        "\"this",
        "is",
        "a",
        "test\""
    ]
},
```

and I want just 3 elements, or at least that whatever strings are after the item[1]=='TXT' be an entire element, and not split.
I would like something like this:

```
{
    "data": "alexandria",
    "name": [
        "alexandria",
        "TXT",
        ""this is a test""
    ]
},
```

I have tried to get whatever after the second element in the dictionary like this:

```
- name: CONVERT STRING DATA INTO A DICTIONARY LIST
  set_fact:
    dict_list: "{{ dict_list|default([]) +
                  [{'data': item | split | first ,
                    'type': item | split()[1] }], 'name': item | split()[2:]  }}"
  loop: "{{ data }}"
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
  separator: "\t"
  dict_list: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in data %}
    {% set arr=i|split(separator)|select|map('trim') %}
    - data: {{ arr[0] }}
      name: {{ arr[1:] }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  dict_list:
    - data: alexandria
      name: [A, 10.10.3.202]
    - data: alexandria
      name: [TXT, '"this is a test"']
    - data: alexandria
      name: [MX, 10 relay.something.com.]
    - data: cname2
      name: [CNAME, alexandria]
    - data: north A 200.200.200.200
      name: []
    - data: cname1 CNAME north
      name: []
    - data: rice CNAME redirect02.testttt.com.
      name: []
    - data: record01 a 10.10.10.10
      name: []
    - data: record02 a 10.10.10.11
      name: []
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    separator: "\t"
    data:
      - "alexandria \tA\t10.10.3.202\t"
      - "alexandria\tTXT\t\"this is a test\"\t"
      - "alexandria\tMX\t10 relay.something.com.\t"
      - "cname2\tCNAME\talexandria\t"
      - "north A 200.200.200.200"
      - "cname1 CNAME north"
      - "rice CNAME redirect02.testttt.com."
      - "record01 a 10.10.10.10    "
      - "record02 a 10.10.10.11    "

    dict_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in data %}
      {% set arr=i|split(separator)|select|map('trim') %}
      - data: {{ arr[0] }}
        name: {{ arr[1:] }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in data %}
          {{ i|split(separator)|select|map('trim') }}
          {% endfor %}

    - debug:
        var: dict_list|to_yaml
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work completely.

The result I want to get is:
    - data: alexandria
      name: [A, 10.10.3.202]
    - data: alexandria
      name: [TXT, '"this is a test"']

I think the separator has to be the default split(), with spaces.

But still.., it doesn't work.

Comment: Select non-empty items and optionally trim the items `i|split(separator)|select|map('trim')`. I fixed the code.